# Windows Structured Storage - 32-bit vs 64-bit COM Interop

Tags: c#, com-interop

While attempting to convert an existing 32-bit application to 64-bit, I've run into trouble getting some COM Interop code to work properly. The code is accessing the structured storage API, using managed code I translated from the various Windows SDK header/IDL files.

The code is failing when I try to call into `IPropertyStorage.ReadMultiple()`, with `STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER`. The previous interop calls, to `StgOpenStorageEx` and `IPropertySetStorage.Open`, appear to work fine. MSDN claims this error means something's wrong with my PROPSPEC parameters, but the same parameter values work fine when compiled as a 32-bit application and the value I get back is the correct string value for the specified property.

Here are what I think are the relevant bits:

```cs
// PropertySpecKind enumeration.
public enum PropertySpecKind : uint
{
    Lpwstr = 0,
    PropId = 1
}

// PropertySpec structure:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PropertySpec
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public PropertySpecKind kind;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public uint propertyId;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public IntPtr name;
}

// PropertyVariant Structure:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PropertyVariant
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public Vartype vt;
    [FieldOffset(8)] public IntPtr pointerValue;
}

// IPropertyStorage interface
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000138-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IPropertyStorage
{
    int ReadMultiple(
        uint count,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 0)] PropertySpec[] properties,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 0)] PropertyVariant[] values);

    void WriteMultiple(
        uint count,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 0)] PropertySpec[] properties,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 0)] PropertyVariant[] values,
        uint miniumumPropertyId);
}

var properties = new PropertySpec[1];
properties[0].kind = PropertySpecKind.PropId; 
properties[0].propertyId = 2;

var propertyValues = new PropertyVariant[1];

// This helper method just calls StgOpenStorageEx with appropriate parameters.
var propertySetStorage = StorageHelper.GetPropertySetStorageReadOnly(fileName);
var propertyStorage = propertySetStorage.Open(StoragePropertySets.PSGUID_SummaryInformation, StorageMode.Read | StorageMode.ShareExclusive);    
propertyStorage.ReadMultiple(1, properties, propertyValues); // Exception is here.
```

Comment: SizeConst = 0 certainly isn't correct, this requires SizeParamIndex.  PropertySpec.name has the wrong offset in 64-bit mode, it is 8.  Good reasons to write this code in C++/CLI btw.

Comment: That is the PROPSPEC structure from the ShellAPI, I just used friendlier names. According to MSDN, "kind" (ulKind) is a ULONG, which   is the same size on both 32- and 64-bit; and "propertyId" (propid) and "name" (lpwstr) are a union so they both should start at offset of 4. Did I get something wrong in there?

Comment: (also, good catch on the SizeConst, dunno how I missed that, but it didn't seem to make any difference...)

Comment: @HansPassant your comments seems to be somehow related with the eventual correct answer, I just can't figure out how. If you can explain why *my* answer solves my problem I'll give you the bounty :)

Comment: Note that all of the above are defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll`, you could probably copy the definitions from there (e.g. with reflector), or simply reference the dll (it's in the GAC though so I'm not sure about deployment)

Comment: Also, in `PropertyVariant`, you can use a union approach instead of `IntPtr` (where you use the actual type you want, e.g. `string` or `int`). See what I did here: https://sourceforge.net/p/tvgamelauncher/code/ci/master/tree/TvGameLauncher/TvGameLauncher/Shell/InternetShortcut/IPropertyStorage.cs

Comment: I just found these definitions in the Windows API Code Pack too: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PropertySpec
{
    public PropertySpecKind kind;
    public PropertySpecData data;
}
```

Yes, that's a good way to declare that structure.  Now you leave it up to the pinvoke interop marshaller to calculate the offset of the *data.name* field and it gets it right.

The *name* field is an IntPtr, it takes 4 bytes in 32-bit mode but 8 bytes in 64-bit mode.  Fields of a structure are aligned to an offset that's an integer multiple of the field size.  The default packing is 8, meaning that any field that's 8 bytes or less will be aligned.  That gives that field an alignment requirement of 4 in 32-bit mode, of 8 in 64-bit mode.  Previously, you forced it at an offset of 4 by using the [FieldOffset(4)] attribute.  Okay for 32-bit code but wrong offset for 64-bit code.

There's some background on structure packing in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: just to make sure I get it: in 64-bit mode, since the `uint` field is in an anonymous union with the `LPWSTR` field, it will also be 8-byte-aligned, even though it only "needs" 4 bytes? That's why my call failed even though I never used the `name` field for anything?

Comment: That's correct.  The *name* field "lifted" the uint field as well.  The way unions work in native code.

Answer (score 1):

After trying multiple iterations of the interop definitions I finally stumbled on an answer. I'm not exactly sure *why* this makes a difference, but the change I made was to replace the single `PROPSPEC` and `PROPVARIANT` structure definitions with nested ones; basically, I split the anonymous unions out into their own types. I assume there is some kind of alignment issue that gets resolved when I do this.

Specifically, the working 32-bit definition of `PROPSPEC` looked like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PropertySpec
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public PropertySpecKind kind;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public uint propertyId;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public IntPtr name;
}
```

I changed that into this, and it now works on both archictectures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct PropertySpec
{
    public PropertySpecKind kind;
    public PropertySpecData data;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct PropertySpecData
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint propertyId;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public IntPtr name;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is exactly what the P/Invoke Interop Assistant does automatically when you feed it the unmanaged signature: http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120

Answer (score 0):

You should define the interface like this:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("00000138-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IPropertyStorage
{
    [PreserveSig]
    uint ReadMultiple(
        uint count,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] PropertySpec[] properties,
        [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] PropertyVariant[] values);

    [PreserveSig]
    uint WriteMultiple(
        uint count,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] PropertySpec[] properties,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)]  PropertySpec[] values,
        uint miniumumPropertyId);

        // other methods left as an exercise to the reader...
}
```

Note the usage of the [PreserveSig attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.preservesigattribute.aspx). Well, it means you'll have to test the return values now :-)

Note: if you need more compound storage p/invoke declarations, you can have a look at this 100% free Nuget tool: [CodeFluent Runtime Client](https://nuget.org/packages/CodeFluentRuntimeClient). It contains a CompoundStorage class utility that you can use, or just inspect it using .NET Reflector or ILSpy and grab the p/invoke definitions it contains. It should support 32 and 64-bit worlds.

Comment: all this does is preserve the signature on the COM calls; the actual behavior is identical. (Instead of throwing `STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER`, now it just returns `STG_E_INVALIDPARAMETER`.)

Comment: No it's not identical. If I don't put the PreserveSig, it does not work, if I do, it does work. Have you tested it?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it both with and without signature rewriting, and both variations worked on 32-bit and both variations failed on 64-bit. The only difference is that the `PreserveSig` calls return an error HRESULT and the rewritten calls wrap the error in an exception and throw it.